# Blender python - Get path animation value at custom (previous) frame

Tags: python, keyframes

I need to get value *Path animation ('eval_time')* of my **['Track_02']** curve from previous frame to calculate acceleration. Therefore on the panel there would be values of *'current_frame'* and the previous frame *('current_frame-1', if correct)* that I can take into calculation. Basicaly display *'eval_time'* values on the *current frame* (which is not a problem) and the *previous one*.
I'm not sure how the last line would go...

Thank you for your help, guys!

Code I used:

````
    def draw (self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        crv = bpy.data.curves['Track_02']
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text = "Current frame")
        row.label(icon = 'TRIA_RIGHT')
        row.operator("object.simple_operator")
        row.prop(crv, 'eval_time')
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text = "Previous frame")
        print(crv, 'eval_time', scene.frame_current-1)```
````

Comment: Will depend on what you are wishing to achieve... If the goal is to calculate acc and vel from animation  It is often "easiest" to bake velocity and acceleration curves. _ie_ animate first, then run a bake script changing to each frame whilst calculating and keyframing v and a.

Comment: Hi, I want to use it for a car rig, I'd prefer the "previous frame option", but I would be glad also for the solution you are proposing, I'll give it a try. Feel free to contribute the code for baking. But I'm relatively new to python, so I hope I'll manage... ;)

Comment: Dated re blender version  but IMO still very much worth a read: [Car rig tutorial from ROUBAL](http://3d-synthesis.com/tutorials/Cars_Animation_Tutorial.pdf)  Cut my teeth on that one many moons ago.

Comment: I have the rig already finished and working - the ROUBAL's rig is on my list, checked that just yesterday and it looks stunning. Nevertheless, I'd like to improve my rig with some realistic y-roll body movement, for which I need these values...

Comment: Please, guys, don't tell me it's impossible to get values from previous frames...